# Dynamic Website - load almost all of the page with out reload and change the url

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, dynamic

I am developing a website and having trouble figuring out what I can use to accomplish this requirement.

I need a website where links in the document load the contents of page that was clicked.

I am thinking about using angular.js but how might a user get back to the back by entering it into the url.

Example of what I am looking for:

---

- You are on www.example.com
- You click the link to www.example.com/profile/1234.
- The page doesn't reload but loads the contents of the new page.
  The static element at the bottom of the page doesn't change the the rest of the page does.
  The url has also changed and you have the history of being at www.example.com
- You can also load the exact same page by pasting the url www.example.com/profile/1234, it also has the same bar at the bottom.

You could also say I need something similar to youtubes website. You click a link and it loads only some of the page. But if you re-enter the url you get all of the page.

Thanks.

Comment: One way is to use Angular UI router, define states.That way, you can use $State.go to reach a particular state, and back.This will take care of URLs too

Comment: @SatejS Actually that might work I have been messing around with angulars ngRoute method but it doesn't do what I like. I will try the ui method.